# Wrap long lines into more than one line inside input of a table td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a long text inside input field that is inside table rows as below

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" disabled="" value="John Doe" id="firstName" name="firstName"></td>
  <td><input type="text" disabled="" value="test" id="custom2" name="custom2"></td>
  <td class="tdthree"><input type="text" disabled="" value="Testing Very Bog Client Name to see How long Before This will  Break . testing Test test test tesyTesting Very Bog aa" id="custom3" name="custom3"></td>
  <td><input type="text" disabled="" value="09-09-1978" id="custom4" name="custom4"></td>
  <td><input type="text" disabled="" value="Tes387314" id="custom1" name="custom1"></td>
</tr>
```

I need the text in tdthree td to wrap into more than one line if longer than td width. I have been searching through google but can not seem to find a cross browser (IE7+) solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `input` wont do this
you can simply use `textarea` to do this for you

Comment: Thanks for the idea. And, can you fix this inside the http://jsfiddle.net/DmzDN maybe?... I am just confused as to how to go with this

Comment: I said that there is no way to wrap text in an input

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS class which has `word-wrap: break-word;`. This will break the long words to the size of your `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

This can done using [**`wordwrap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap), which allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line.

```
.tdthree {
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

You can't add newline inside `textbox`, however you can try with `textarea`.

Comment: but this will target contents of TD and not the input tag.

Comment: @Himu you can't use newline in `textbox`.  If I understand right then you should move on to `textarea`.

Comment: @Himu check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DmzDN/5/, however there is  no need to break work here in textarea since it already adjust to auto.

Comment: Awesome @user1671639 . Thanks. It got solved through the above fiddle solution. :) Thanks

Comment: @Himu I'm glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

there is a CSS property which you can apply to input box

text-overflow: ellipsis;

You can have a [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) here.

Comment: But this will not let input box extend the height, it will just limit the number of text to be shown on display

Comment: I made it clear that it should be applied to the input box and as I can see your code, you are targeting the TD. How do you think it will work?

Comment: Buddy your solution in jsFiddle does not work!!! Please read the question properly first.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `word-break: break-word;` for your td element.

Answer (score 0):

Use white-space: normal; that will solve the problem